# Update reactive object with two actionbuttons in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny app below in which the user uploads a file (here I just put the dt in a reactive function) and from there he can choose which columns he wants to display as `selectInput()` via a `pickerInput()`. Then he should be able to click on `Update` and see the table.

The user should also be able to update the `value1` values by multiplying  all of them with the `numericInput()` `value1` and create a new `sliderInput()` and therefore update the dataframe that is displayed in the table as well. These changes should be applied only when the user clicks on `Update2` actionbutton.

The problem is that dataframe should basically be affected by 2 actionbuttons and Im not sure that can be applied. The `Update2` will work only when the `numericInput()` `value1` is used.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
# ui object

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel(p("Spatial app", style = "color:#3474A7")),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            uiOutput("inputp1"),
            #Add the output for new pickers
            uiOutput("pickers"),
            actionButton("button", "Update")
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
            DTOutput("table"),
            numericInput("num", label = ("value"), value = 1),
            actionButton("button2", "Update 2")
            
        )
    )
)

# server()
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    DF1 <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
    
    dt <- reactive({
        name<-c("John","Jack","Bill")
        value1<-c(2,4,6)
        dt<-data.frame(name,value1)
    })
    
    observe({
        DF1$data <- dt()
    })
    
    output$inputp1 <- renderUI({
        pickerInput(
            inputId = "p1",
            label = "Select Column headers",
            choices = colnames( dt()),
            multiple = TRUE,
            options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
        )
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$p1, {
        #Create the new pickers
        output$pickers<-renderUI({
            dt1 <- DF1$data
            div(lapply(input$p1, function(x){
                if (is.numeric(dt1[[x]])) {
                    sliderInput(inputId=x, label=x, min=min(dt1[[x]]), max=max(dt1[[x]]), value=c(min(dt1[[x]]),max(dt1[[x]])))
                }else { # if (is.factor(dt1[[x]])) {
                    selectInput(
                        inputId = x,       # The col name of selected column
                        label = x,         # The col label of selected column
                        choices = dt1[,x], # all rows of selected column
                        multiple = TRUE
                    )
                }
                
            }))
        })
    })
    
    
    dt2 <- eventReactive(input$button, {
        req(input$num)
        dt <- DF1$data ## here you can provide the user input data read inside this observeEvent or recently modified data DF1$data
        dt$value1<-dt$value1*isolate(input$num)
        
        dt
    })
    observe({DF1$data <- dt2()})
    
    output_table <- reactive({
        req(input$p1, sapply(input$p1, function(x) input[[x]]))
        dt_part <- dt2()
        for (colname in input$p1) {
            if (is.factor(dt_part[[colname]]) && !is.null(input[[colname]])) {
                dt_part <- subset(dt_part, dt_part[[colname]] %in% input[[colname]])
            } else {
                if (!is.null(input[[colname]][[1]])) {
                    dt_part <- subset(dt_part, (dt_part[[colname]] >= input[[colname]][[1]]) & dt_part[[colname]] <= input[[colname]][[2]])
                }
            }
        }
        dt_part
    })
    
    output$table<-renderDT({
        output_table()
    })
    
}

# shinyApp()
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, I am not clear if you are referring to `value1` as a variable name in your data frame or `numericInput` value.  Perhaps you are looking for this.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
# ui object

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(p("Spatial app", style = "color:#3474A7")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("inputp1"),
      #Add the output for new pickers
      actionButton("button", "Update"),
      uiOutput("pickers"),
      numericInput("num", label = ("value"), value = 1),
      actionButton("button2", "Update 2")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("table")
     
      
    )
  )
)

# server()
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  DF1 <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
  
  dt <- reactive({
    name<-c("John","Jack","Bill")
    value1<-c(2,4,6)
    dt<-data.frame(name,value1)
  })
  
  observe({
    DF1$data <- dt()
  })
  
  output$inputp1 <- renderUI({
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "p1",
      label = "Select Column headers",
      choices = colnames( dt()),
      multiple = TRUE,
      options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$p1, {
    #Create the new pickers
    output$pickers<-renderUI({
      dt1 <- DF1$data
      div(lapply(input$p1, function(x){
        if (is.numeric(dt1[[x]])) {
          sliderInput(inputId=x, label=x, min=min(dt1[[x]]), max=max(dt1[[x]]), value=c(min(dt1[[x]]),max(dt1[[x]])))
        }else { # if (is.factor(dt1[[x]])) {
          selectInput(
            inputId = x,       # The col name of selected column
            label = x,         # The col label of selected column
            choices = dt1[,x], # all rows of selected column
            multiple = TRUE
          )
        }
        
      }))
    })
  })
  
  
  dt2 <- eventReactive(input$button2, {
    req(input$num)
    dt <- DF1$data ## here you can provide the user input data read inside this observeEvent or recently modified data DF1$data
    dt$value1<-dt$value1*isolate(input$num)
    
    dt
  })
  observe({DF1$data <- dt2()})
  
  output_table <- reactive({
    req(input$p1, sapply(input$p1, function(x) input[[x]]))
    dt_part <- dt2()
    for (colname in input$p1) {
      if (is.factor(dt_part[[colname]]) && !is.null(input[[colname]])) {
        dt_part <- subset(dt_part, dt_part[[colname]] %in% input[[colname]])
      } else {
        if (!is.null(input[[colname]][[1]])) {
          dt_part <- subset(dt_part, (dt_part[[colname]] >= input[[colname]][[1]]) & dt_part[[colname]] <= input[[colname]][[2]])
        }
      }
    }
    dt_part
  })
  
  output$table<-renderDT({
    if (input$button | input$button2) {
      DF1$data
    }else return(NULL)
  })
  
}

# shinyApp()
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Yes its as you understood it.

Comment: I found an issue with the subseting part of your method.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63845641/subseting-a-dataset-does-not-work-as-it-gives-every-time-the-same-dataset